# How do I change or add an additional HTML Publishing Template in Flash CS6?

Tags: html, flash, publishing

How do I update or add an additional HTML template in Flash Professional CS6? I have tried the instructions in http://adobe.ly/uCPsvf and neither changes to existing templates or new templates appear in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adobe site is wrong (at least for the Mac version).
Their "Customize HTML publishing templates" portion **lies**:

> /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/*language*/First Run/HTML

You **want** to be poking around in:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Flash CS6/*en_US*/Configuration/HTML/